# Python programm for files

Tags: python, file

I am trying to make a programm that:

1. will save in a file named "class.txt" the full names of students of a class (one per line)
2. Then I have to insert the names:

- Karamitsos Giorgos
- Patapoukas Dimitris

and then close the file.

3. Read the file and print only the first names.

Following is my attempt:

```py
f = open('class.txt','w')
l = ['karamitsos giorgos \n', 'patapoukas dimitris \n']
f.writelines(l)
f.close()
f1 = open('class.txt','r')
l2 = str(f1.readlines())
l3 = list(l2.split(" "))
print(l3,'\n')
print(l3[1], l3[4])
f1.close()
```

Comment: Cool, you have a problem statement and you have some code. How does this code fail to do what you want? Are you getting an error message? Is it doing something unexpected? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? See [ask].

Comment: Why `str(f1.readlines())` and then split it again when you already get a list of lines from just using `f1.readlines()`?

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

1. The output file should probably be opened using mode 'a', which instead of erasing any old file's contents will instead append new data to the end.
2. By using a *context manager* to open the file, e.g. `with open('class.txt', 'a') as f:`, the file will automatically be closed when the `with` block is exited.
3. Method `readlines` will read the entire file into memory in one shot. What if the file has megabytes of data? You should instead iteratively read the file line by line.
4. You can use `print` to add additional names to the file. By default a newline will be appended to the end of whatever you are printing.

```py
with open('class.txt','a') as f:
    for name in ('karamitsos giorgos', 'patapoukas dimitris'):
        print(name, file=f)

with open('class.txt', 'r') as f:
    for name in f:
        name_parts = name.strip().split(' ')
        print(name_parts[0])
```

However, you can avoid opening and closing the file twice by opening it once for both appending and reading:

```py
with open('class.txt','a+') as f:
    for name in ('karamitsos giorgos', 'patapoukas dimitris'):
        print(name, file=f)

    # Seek to beginning of the file:
    f.seek(0, 0)

    for name in f:
        name_parts = name.strip().split(' ')
        print(name_parts[0])
```